# right align and description

Tags: horizontal-alignment

How to align **(9) A** to right?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item [Hlavní poloosa] (9) A \\
$a$ může být určena 
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\item [Hlavní poloosa] \hfill(9) A \\
```